# Generics and returning class objects

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to return an object of a class using the generics.

This is the generic class

```
public class ClientBase <S>
{
    protected S CreateObject()
    {
        return default(S)  ;
    }
}
```

This is how I am trying to use it...

```
public class ClientUser : ClientBase <SomeClass>
{

    public void call()
    {
        var client = this.CreateObject();
        client.SomeClassMethod();
     }
}
```

While I get the `SomeClassMethod()` in the client object, when running the code it gives an error at the line:

client.SomeClassMethod();

Error is 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'. I know there is something missing in the generic class ClientBase's CreateObject() method; just cant figure that bit out. Could someone help me here please?

Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`default(S)` where `S` is a reference type is null. In your case, `default(SomeClass)` returns null. When you try to invoke a method on a null reference, that's when you get your exception.

Are you trying to return a default instance of `SomeClass`? You may want to use a `new()` constraint and `return new S()` in your generic class instead, like so:

```
public class ClientBase<S> where S : new()
{
    protected S CreateObject()
    {
        return new S();
    }
}
```

If `S` needs to be a reference type you can also constrain it to `class`:

```
public class ClientBase<S> where S : class, new()
{
    protected S CreateObject()
    {
        return new S();
    }
}
```

Comment: edited my question... missed out putting the actual error. :)

Comment: yup trying to return instance. I tried that what you put. now I get this... Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: @user20358: It's likely that some other code in your program is causing such an exception.

Comment: @user20358: check the InnerException of the TargetInvocationException for the actual exception

Answer (score 2):

See what `default(T)` does: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx

In your case, `default(S)` is going to return null (because it's a class) - this is not an instance of the class.

You either need to call `new S()` or some other `S` constructor or override `CreateObject` in your derived class.